# abundance of "full" couples

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $G$ be a finite set, and let $\mathcal A$ be a subset of $\mathcal P(G)$, we denote by $max(\mathcal A)$ the set of maximal elements of $\mathcal A$ (for inclusion)

For any $A\in \mathcal A$ we denote by $\mathcal A_A=\left\{X\in \mathcal A,\, X\subsetneq A\right\}$

We say that $a\in G$ is *full* in $Y\in \mathcal A$, (or that $(a,Y)$ is a full couple) and write $F_{\mathcal A}(a,Y)$ if $a\in \bigcap max(\mathcal A_Y)$

and we define $F_{\mathcal A}(a,.):=\left\{Y\in \mathcal A,\,\, F_{\mathcal A}(a,Y)\right\}$

---

Question

> Does there exists a constant $C<1$ such that for any finite set $G$ and any $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal P(G)$ there exists $a\in G$, such that 
>   $|F_{\mathcal A}(a,.)|/|\mathcal A|\leq C$ 
>   ?

---

For example if $G_1=\left\{a,b,c,d\right\}$, and  $\mathcal A_1= \left\{\emptyset,\left\{a\right\},\left\{a,b\right\},\left\{a,b,c\right\},G_1\right\}$ then, for any $x\in G_1$ and any non empty $Y\in \mathcal A_1$, $x$ is full in $Y$ iff $Y\triangle \left\{x\right\}\notin \mathcal A_1$ (fulls are one side off the "diagonal")

Other example : if $\mathcal A_2$
 is a finite *down-set* with ground set $G_2$, then  $F_{\mathcal A_2}(x,.)$ is empty for any $x\in G_2$.

One can show that if $\mathcal A'$ is closed under intersection with ground set $G'$ then for ANY $x\in G'$ we have :

$|\left\{A\in \mathcal A', x\in A\right\}|\leq(|\mathcal A'|+|F_{\mathcal A'}(x,.)|)/2$

This last remark shows the link between the question and the Frankl Conjecture 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but how is $cov(A)$ well-defined? Let $G=\{1,2,3\}$, and let $\mathcal A=\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\,\{1,2,3\}\}$. What is $cov(\{1\})$?

Comment: oh, thank you, I changed notation and definition and I had a "mix", let me correct!